Cannot execute stored procedure in Oracle19c
I am currently facing an issue(below is the error code) when trying to import data from a .csv file to OracleDB. Now, I have a stored procedure so that I could easily call it out. Now, every time I try to run or call the stored procedure it gives me an error(error code below)
So this is my stored procedure called load_csv_into_employee;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_csv_into_employee AS
   v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Checking if the external table already exists...');

   -- Check if the external table already exists
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO v_count
   FROM user_tables
   WHERE table_name = 'CSV_TABLE';

   -- If the external table doesn't exist, create it
   IF v_count = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating the external table...');
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
         CREATE TABLE csv_table (
            EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR2(50),
            FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
            LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
            DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(200)
         )
         ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
            TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
            DEFAULT DIRECTORY csv_dir
            ACCESS PARAMETERS (
               RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
               FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''
               MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
            )
            LOCATION (''mssql_data.csv'')
         )';
   END IF;

   -- Insert data into EMPLOYEE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting data into EMPLOYEE...');
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
      INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
      SELECT * FROM csv_table';

   -- Drop the external table
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dropping the external table...');
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE csv_table';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Committing changes...');
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END load_csv_into_employee;
/

However it gives me this error every time I execute it:
Error: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout.
I tried(Most of the answers I searched they based on permission issue):

I have tried researching here and found that there might be a permission issues. So I made sure that I have created the csv_dir using the syntax
CREATE DIRECTORY csv_dir AS '\\dir\path\your_file.csv'; and also made sure that I have granted it with permission.  GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY csv_dir TO MyUserName;. I used the sys as sysdba user to grant permission for this one

Note: I am currently just trying to test and learn so I had to use the SYS user.
EDIT: I have added print on every execution, so it stops on the Inserting data into EMPLOYEE and then the error shows up.


It’s generally a good idea to make sure statements that you want to run dynamically work correctly statically first - so create and query the external table manually and get that working before trying to do it in a procedure. Do you really need to create and drop the table at runtime? Why not just create it manually once - then you can avoid dynamic SQL.

Remove the exception handler and re-run the procedure. Instead of printing out only the top of the error stack, let Oracle raise and display the entire error stack. I bet there's a more useful error message underneath the generic ORA-29913.

The location is relative to the directory object, not the full path; so
LOCATION (''\\directory\path\your_file.csv'')

should just be
LOCATION (''your_file.csv'')

and the directory object is the path to the OS directory/folder (which has to be on the database server), so:
CREATE DIRECTORY csv_dir AS '\\dir\path';


Hello Alex, I appreciate the help. I have updated the location path and now it is LOCATION (''mssql_data.csv'').
However it still produces the same error code.

Is the directory on the database server, rather than a client machine? You showed the directory creation with the file name as part of that path, which isn't correct - but not sure if that's a mistake writing the question?

You are correct,  when I created and executed the create directory, I have included the file name as well.
Now, I have dropped the csv_dir directory and created a new one with a directory path only \\dir\path like what you have mentioned in your reply.
However, the same error still shows. I have double checked it before replying to you. Thank you!

You need to re-grant the read/write privilege ls too. Is that directory on the database server? Does the user Oracle runs under have read/write permissions at operating system level, on the directory and file?
